# How to get Postfix and Dovecot working with an existing Kerberos realm?

Tags: imap, smtp, postfix, dovecot, kerberos

I now have a Kerberos realm like `MYDOMAIN.CH`, an admin server and a principal of `root/admin`, as well as the realm master password and the `root/admin` principal password. Now I want to get Kerberos authentication set up with Postfix and Dovecot, in order to let clients to authenticate using Kerberos, and sending/receiving emails in an authenticated fashion.

I have conducted some research on Google before asking this question, and unfortunately have not found any results (and the RedHat one is behind an unbypassable hard paywall).

What configurations do I need to tweak, especially the authentication configurations in the configuration files order to achieve this goal? Also, I would need to use a dedicated Unix socket like `private/auth` for Kerberos so that the authentication only happens in a relatively secure way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kerberos 5 is used through the GSS API. All relevant mail protocols use the SASL authentication framework, where `GSSAPI` is the SASL mechanism name for Kerberos-via-GSS.

So if you want Dovecot to use GSSAPI, first **enable it in auth_mechanisms:**

```
auth_mechanisms = $auth_mechanisms gssapi
```

POP3 and IMAP4 use the `pop` and `imap` GSS service names respectively, so Dovecot needs Kerberos principals `pop/<fqdn>` and `imap/<fqdn>` created in the Kerberos realm. You must export their keys into a keytab, whose path is then configured as:

```
auth_krb5_keytab = /etc/dovecot/dovecot.keytab
```

Kerberos clients will follow CNAMEs to canonicalize the service principal, so if your clients connect to `imap.example.com` which is 'CNAME'd to `mailsrv.example.com`, usually only the latter is used by Kerberos. But also note that older MIT Krb5 and Heimdal will, by default, also use *reverse DNS* to look up the server principal, so make sure the rDNS for the server's all IPv4/IPv6 addresses matches its real "canonical" name.

---

For Postfix, you have two options: Cyrus SASL and Dovecot SASL. It's easiest to use the latter since you already have it set up, so the only Postfix configuration changes needed will be those in **[Postfix and Dovecot SASL](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/postfix_and_dovecot_sasl/)**.

SMTP uses the `smtp` GSS service name, so you'll need to create a `smtp/<fqdn>` Kerberos principal. However, when SASL is handled by Dovecot, keys for this principal also go into *Dovecot's* keytab – Postfix doesn't need one.

---

If, however, for some reason you decide to use Cyrus SASL as your `smtp_sasl_type`, then you will need to create a libsasl configuration file for the 'smtp' service at `/etc/sasl2/smtp.conf` (note that older versions expect it at `/usr/lib/sasl2` instead):

```
mech_list: GSSAPI
keytab: /etc/postfix/postfix.keytab
```

With Cyrus SASL in use, GSSAPI is handled by *libsasl* internally within Postfix, so there is no need to set up additional sockets.

A downside is that Cyrus libsasl may have different logic than Dovecot (e.g. regarding principal-to-username translation), so you could end up with a slightly inconsistent service for your mail server.

You **do not** need to run the saslauthd daemon for Kerberos authentication. Its purpose is to handle *password* authentication, e.g. it can check received passwords against a Kerberos realm (directly or via PAM), but having the client submit a password is *not* Kerberos authentication regardless of what backend it uses.

---

For SSH, the GSS service name is `host`, and the keytab is always `/etc/krb5.keytab`. You also need to enable Kerberos as GSSAPI in the server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

(Do not pay attention to the `KerberosAuthentication` setting: its purpose is actually like saslauthd's, in that it actually handles *password* authentication and only verifies the received password against Kerberos by trying to acquire a ticket, but is not "true" Kerberos authentication.)

---

For HTTP/HTTPS, the service name is `HTTP` (upper-case). A small difference from the above protocols is that HTTP typically uses SPNEGO as an additional negotiation layer (i.e. Kerberos-in-SPNEGO-via-GSS) and you'll find more documentation referring to "SPNEGO" or "Negotiate" rather than Kerberos on its own.

Apache supports Kerberos through the external `mod_auth_gssapi` module, which is fully documented [elsewhere](https://github.com/gssapi/mod_auth_gssapi#basic-configuration). Do not use the obsolete mod_auth_kerb module – though it does the same thing, but is practically unmaintained. Nginx has an `spnego` module, but it seems to be part of the commercial "NGINX Plus" product.

Note that although you can use Kerberos with HTTP, this won't automatically result in single sign-on for webmail, as the webserver cannot forward the same authentication data to a different service. For that you would need either the whole TGT to be forwarded (unconstrained delegation), or impersonation via S4U (constrained delegation), or impersonation via SASL (authorization identity).